# Bonmin fails with error code -9 from ASL (AMPL solver library), what does that code even mean?

Tags: python, ampl, ipopt, coin-or-cbc

I am trying to solve a linear problem using Bonmin, the sample size is 5000 records. Ipopt and Cbc solved the same problem and data without any issues. Whereas, Bonmin always fails with the below error:
ERROR: Solver (asl) returned non-zero return code (-9)
ERROR: Solver log: Bonmin 1.8.8 using Cbc 2.10.4 and Ipopt 3.12.12 bonmin:

```
**************************************************************************
**** This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear
optimization.
 Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License
 (EPL).
         For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
**************************************************************************
****

NLP0012I
              Num      Status      Obj             It       time
              Location
NLP0014I             1         OPT 8.6428145       50 113.49967 NLP0014I
7         OPT 95.995942       28 71.954289 NLP0012I
              Num      Status      Obj             It       time
              Location
NLP0014I             1         OPT 95.995942       23 63.271429 Cbc0012I
Integer solution of 95.995942 found by FPump after 0 iterations and 0
nodes (3926.59 seconds) NLP0014I             2         OPT 8.6428145
52 172.52402 NLP0014I             3         OPT 8.6428145       55
207.97475 NLP0014I             4         OPT 8.6428145       52 199.05354
NLP0014I             5         OPT 8.6428145       55 206.76115 NLP0014I
6         OPT 8.6428145       52 199.58511
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/app/binpackingLargeBonminSingle.py", line 64, in 
results = opt.solve(instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", line 596, in solve
"Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)
pyomo.common.errors.ApplicationError: Solver (asl) did not exit normally

What does an error code -9 from ASL even mean?
FYI: This problem is in a Linux environment. In Windows, Bonmin takes forever to solve the problem and never gave any output/ error, it's always in a running state. and I've installed Bonmin through Coinbrew- if this info helps in any way.

I've checked the ASL.py and solvers.py for insights into this error code and found nothing. Any help is appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

The OS killed the solver, mostly because the latter asked for too much memory and the former ran out of more to give.